# distribute n distinct objects into k non empty sets, what is the expected number of sets of cardinality p in a valid partition

Tags: combinatorics

The title pretty much says it all, if we distribute n distinct objects into k non empty sets, is there a formula to determine the expected number of sets of cardinality p in a valid partition?

Answer (score 0):

Start by distributing 1 object into each of the $k$ sets.  Once you have done so, you have $n-k$ objects that you are free to distribute however you want.  A multinomial distribution can give you the probability of each set having $p-1$ of the $n-k$ objects, and the expected number will be that probability times $k$.

Comment: Had to read about multinomial distributions to wrap my head around this. Correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding is multinomial distributions are applicable only when the subsequent trials are independent which is not the case here: if we consider our trial to be the forming of a random set the cardinality of the formed set affects the probability of forming subsequent sets with p elements, which makes the trials dependent here.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are $S(n,k)$ partitions of $n$ labelled objects in $k$
unlabelled nonempty sets (Stirling number of second kind). Assume
all these partitions are equiprobable. What is the probability that
a particular $p$-element set occurs. Clearly $S(n-p,k-1)/S(n,k)$
as there are $n-p$ further objects to put into $k-1$ boxes. There are
$\binom{n}{p}$ such $p$-element sets, so by linearity of expectation,
the expected number is
$$\binom{n}{p}\frac{S(n-p,k-1)}{S(n,k)}.$$

Comment: Interesting although I'm a bit confused to be honest, calculating the probability of appearance of a particular p-element set without considering how many other p-element sets are expected to co-exist with it is not clicking in my head. I'll test this with a brute force and get back to you. Thanks for the quick answer, I wish I could up vote!

Comment: This is the power of "linearity of expectation". We introduce the indicator random variable for each possible $p$-element set (value $1$ if the set occurs and $0$ if not). Its expectation is the probability of that set occurring. Adding these up gives the number of $p$-element sets in a random partition. The expectation of a sum is the sum of the expectations.

Comment: That all sounds reasonable, except that the probability of appearance of a second set of cardinality p in the same partition is not the same as the first, and same applies to the 3rd and so on. This is to say the subsequent probabilities of appearance are strongly interdependent if that makes sense. I just tested your formula with n = 6, k = 3, p = 2 your formula gave 7 * 20 / 90, whereas the correct expected value should be 105/90.

Comment: Here's how I calculated the 105: there are only 3 possible set size configurations i.e. (4, 1, 1) repeated 6 choose 4 times = **15** (here no set of size 2 appears). then we have (3, 2, 1) repeated 6 choose 3 times, multiplied by 3 choose 2 times = **60** each having exactly **1** set of size 2, and finally (2, 2, 2) repeated 6 choose 2 times, multiplied by 4 choose 2 times divided by 3! (to eliminate permutations) = **15** each having exactly **3** sets of size 2. 60 * 1 + 15 * 3 = 105